# Bundle.main.path(forResource:ofType:inDirectory:)

Tags: json, bundle

I am trying to load a json file from my bundle, but only say the first 100 entries. Is it possible to use Bundle.main.path(for...) with something like the "&limit=Int" used on the url for fetching from an API?

I want to NOT have to load the entire file into my array.

I'm using a simple/nice example from Paul Hudson json fetching songs from itunes api. This loader works fine. I'm just wondering how to handle a larger file, for later on. I have found the .prefix(Int) to trim my array, but I'd like to not have to load the entire file.

'''

```
func loadData() {
        /* guard let url = URL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=taylor+swift&entity=song&limit=\(count)") else {
         print("Invalid URL")
         return
         } */
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "TaylorSwift12", withExtension: "json") else { fatalError("Could not find TaylorSwift.json") }
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            if let data = data {
                if let decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data) {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.results = decodedResponse.results
                    }
                    return
                }
            }
            print("Fetch failed: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")
        }.resume()
    }
```

'''

Comment: OK, I don't see how to enter code yet...

Comment: you can't load part of a json file into memory, you might want to split it into multiple files if it's too large.

Comment: this stackoverflow answer some how doesn't surprise me